# GlassFish does't open new window for I do login in Outh2 by Api Google

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I made ​​a program in JSE (Eclipse -Mars ). This is what makes a user session and a button automatically opens a pop-up window to log into `Google OAuth2`.

I am making a web application (GlassFish + NetBeans) with this program and the problem is that the window does not open Google. I think a conflict of `glassfish` and `jetty - 6.1.26.jar`

**Console Netbeans:**

```
Grave:   2016-09-05 20:47:39.132:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
Grave:   2016-09-05 20:47:39.135:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
Grave:   2016-09-05 20:47:39.169:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:47808
```

any help is welcome, thanks in advance